# Next JS App Dockerfile build locally but fails in Cloud Run when CI/CD

Tags: docker, webpack, next.js, gcloud, google-cloud-run

While trying to implement CI/CD in Cloud Run using a Dockerfile, it fails as if some fail were not found. I have built the same container locally with no issues. Here is my Dockerfile:

NextJS version: 12.0.1

Docker: 4.4.2

```
# Install dependencies only when needed
FROM node:16-alpine AS deps
# Check https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/tree/b4117f9333da4138b03a546ec926ef50a31506c3#nodealpine to understand why libc6-compat might be needed.
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile

# Rebuild the source code only when needed
FROM node:16-alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
RUN yarn build 



# Production image, copy all the files and run next
FROM node:16-alpine AS runner
WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV production

RUN addgroup -g 1001 -S nodejs
RUN adduser -S nextjs -u 1001

# You only need to copy next.config.js if you are NOT using the default configuration
COPY --from=builder /app/next.config.js ./
COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next ./.next
COPY --from=builder /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=builder /app/package.json ./package.json

USER nextjs

EXPOSE 3000

ENV PORT 3000

# Next.js collects completely anonymous telemetry data about general usage.
# Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/telemetry
# Uncomment the following line in case you want to disable telemetry.
# ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

The error displayed is the following:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2InLV.png)

Does anyone know what could be the problem here?

Comment: It looks like your folders reference do not match with the actual folders structure you have in the container. I would suggest you to build the docker image locally and exec into it to debug and set the correct path across your project.

Comment: Please post your CloudBuild definition for people to be able to help you

Comment: Can you show your `components` folder structure? This could be a casing issue with the import paths. Make sure the paths exactly match the names of the files you're importing.

Comment: I fixed the error while checking my folder structure in GitHub and not locally. I notice a discrepancy of names. Lower case from uppercase. 

GitHub didn’t update my folder and files when I renamed them a while ago. 

Cloud run is building the container from GitHub. 

I fixed the issue by running git core.ignorecase false and then pushing the changes.

Comment: Please read "[Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/128421)"
and "[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812)"

Answer (score 2):

Are you on MacOS ? I had a similar issue a few weeks ago. The issue was casing : [APFS is case insensitive by default](https://support.apple.com/lv-lv/guide/disk-utility/dsku19ed921c/mac). So everything worked on my local machine but failed when running on Linux.

Comment: I fixed the error while checking my folder structure in GitHub and not locally. I notice a discrepancy of names. Lower case from uppercase. 

GitHub didn’t update my folder and files when I renamed them a while ago. 

Cloud run is building the container from GitHub. 

I fixed the issue by running git core.ignorecase false and then pushing the changes.